# JavaScript - function to get real image width & height (cross browser)

Tags: javascript, image, height, width

How to get real image width & height (cross browser) by JavaScript function ?

Comment: "as the title" is unacceptable text, you are asking others to take sometime to answer your question, do the curtesy of taking some time to ask your question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all, you have a greater chance of getting your question answered if you'd just ask it in a more polite way, and supplying as much relevant information as possible.

Anyway...

For as far as I know, you can use the **`.width` property** across pretty much all browsers:

```
function getDimensions(id) {
    var element = document.getElementById(id);
    if (element && element.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {
        return {
            width: element.width,
            height: element.height
        };
    }
}

<img id="myimage" src="foo.jpg" alt="" />

// using the function on the above image:
var dims = getDimensions('myimage');
alert(dims.width); --> shows width
alert(dims.height); --> shows height
```

Comment: height misreports in IE11

Answer (score 8):

```
var realWidth = $("#image").attr("naturalWidth");
var realHeight = $("#image").attr("naturalHeight");
```

Comment: where is the documentation for this?

Answer (score 4):

Yay, [Google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=javascript+image+width+height)!

There's a few ways to do this depending on exactly what you need (which you have unhelpfully omitted to include).  Probably the simplest in a general sense is to get a reference to the Image object and inspect the `width` and `height` properties.

Comment: I like to give this to people when it's obvious they did not google: http://letmegooglethatforyou.com/?q=javascript+image+width+height

Comment: For me, this very page is the result of that Google search today.

Comment: I can assure you it wasn't when I posted this two-and-a-half years ago. :)

Answer (score 0):

jquery + `<img src="" ... id="hello" />` + `$("#hello").width()`