# Getting the width of an image without an assigned width using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, width

I have the following code which needs to get the width of an image which is dynamically loaded, when a thumbnail is clicked on.

```
$("<img class='mypopupimage' src='" + imgSrc + "' style='padding:10px;' width='500' />").appendTo("div.mydiv");

var imgWidth = $(".mypopupimage").width();
```

The trouble I have is that the popup images are all different widths, but when I remove the width attribute from the image the imgWidth variable gets set to 0.

Any ideas?

Comment: Dublicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439358/javascript-function-to-get-real-image-width-height-cross-browser): Try $(".mypopupimage").attr("naturalWidth");

Comment: Awesome, thanks... if you add this as an answer I can accept it as the correct one...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get image size (height & width) using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Comment: Tom just upvote the accepted answer in the duplicate if it helped you as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has already been answered multiple times on stack, however, here it is for ease:

[clientWidth](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientWidth) and [clientHeight](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientheight) are DOM properties that show the current in-browser size of the inner dimensions of a DOM element (excluding margin and border). So in the case of an IMG element, this will get the actual dimensions of the visible image.

```
var img = document.getElementById('imageid'); 
//or however you get a handle to the IMG
var width = img.clientWidth;
var height = img.clientHeight;
```

This answer is taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the attribute naturalWidth if you want to use jQuery or go with the "normal" javascript as stated by udjamaflip:

```
$("<img class='mypopupimage' src='" + imgSrc + "' style='padding:10px;' width='500' />").appendTo("div.mydiv");
var imgWidth = $(".mypopupimage").attr('naturalWidth');
```